# Bootstrap Modal init and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I face an issue with bootstrap modal, what I'm trying to do is to insert HTML contents inside bootstrap modal using AJAX but when I load the modal nothing is displayed and when I inspect the modal I can see the html contents from AJAX, I figured out that this because the time that is needed to initialize the modal faster than the time that AJAX takes to load the html contents.

Is there a way to make the modal and the AJAX load at the same time or if there is another way to make html contents from ajax display inside a modal body.

The Modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="MobileAppPromoDiv">
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</a>
</div>
```

The Ajax:

```
$.get("URL",{action:21},function(htmlContent){
     $('#MobileAppPromoDiv').find('.modal-body').append(htmlContent);
                $('#MobileAppPromoDiv').modal('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to initialize the modal during the AJAX call so both will be initialized at the same time and displayed correctly.

```
$.get("URL",{action:21},function(htmlContent){
 $('#MobileAppPromoDiv').find('.modal-body').append(htmlContent);
 $('#MobileAppPromoDiv').modal('show').on('shown', initHtml);
});
```

And in the initHTML function I placed the initialization for the html page I want for ex. 
`$(document).ready(function() { . . . }` so the html page would be ready in the time of modal initialization

I hope this would be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

You can setTimeout() method to delay the madel initialization for some time to load the HTML content using AJAX.